# Replacing ampersand with the word and in URL's using existing str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm needing to replace ampersand (`&`) with the word `and` in URL's and am already replacing spaces with hyphens using php `str_replace` like below:-

```
<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $value)) ?>
```

Am I able to modify this to add the replacement of ampersands as well by using an array perhaps?

Comment: You want to perform both replacements in the same statement, or...?

Comment: Yes please, ideally. That's what I've struggled to find an example of online so far.

Comment: I've added an answer to fulfil this need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace both strings in one statement, do the following;

```
<?php

$find = array(" ", "&");
$replace = array("-", "and");

$string = "Hello I am a man & I have a dog";

echo str_replace($find, $replace, $string); //Output: Hello-I-am-a-man-and-I-have-a-dog
```

http://codepad.org/nGj26mNc

A more elegant way would be to have one associative array. (http://codepad.org/OgogWK5l)

```
<?php

$findAndReplace = array(" " => "-", "&" => "and");

$string = "Hello I am a man & I have a dog";

echo str_replace(array_keys($findAndReplace), array_values($findAndReplace), $string);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do - just hadn't got the syntax correct - awesome, thanks @hd.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question "if you are able to do using array" is yes. You should read documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Also, if you just want to encode url you should try to use : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
or
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

as per your requirement.

Comment: I'm already looking at the `str_preplace` docs but could not find an example of what I'm trying to do. That is only when I posted here. It's all well and good posting links to documentation but I try that first before posting on here.

Comment: @zigojacko your question never suggest if you look for documentation and didn't find solution. However if you look for #2 example in documentation it shows how we can use Array Replace within function. :) so, you understand now why I post URL. "Reading is Best teacher"...

Comment: I agree, it is - I was trying those examples but couldn't get it working - perhaps I should have explained that in my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of replacing ampersand with a word, you can ecode it using encodeURIComponent() function.

Check this
[URL Encoding—Ampersand Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012810/url-encoding-ampersand-problem)

Comment: But the URL already exists with the word 'and' in. My string is like `one & two` and the URL, I need to match it to is `one-and-two`.